# How to fix : PothosSchemaError [GraphQLError]: Ref ObjectRef<timeLogs> has not been implemented

Tags: javascript, graphql

PothosSchemaError [GraphQLError]: Ref ObjectRef has not been implemented.

if I run `pnpm dev` and get this error, how do I fix it?

PothosSchemaError [GraphQLError]: Ref ObjectRef has not been implemented

```
`timeLogs.ts` code


import { schemaBuilder } from '@api/schemaBuilder';
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql/error';
import { db } from '@api/drizzle';
import { and, eq } from 'drizzle-orm';
import { TimeLogs } from '@modules/projectManagement/types';
import { timeLogs } from '@modules/projectManagement/db/timeLogs';

schemaBuilder.queryField('timeLogs', (t) =>
  t.field({
    type: [TimeLogs],
    nullable: true,
    args: {
      organisationId: t.arg.string({ required: true }),
    },

    async resolve(root, { organisationId }) {
      try {
        return await db.query.timeLogs.findMany({
          where: and(eq(timeLogs.projectOrganisationId, organisationId)),
        });
      } catch (error) {
        throw new GraphQLError('data-fetch-error');
      }
    },
  }),
);
```